# Cannot Record twice Android

Tags: android, record

I am making an app where i can record something and then play it back but when i try to record again my APP crashes.

In the logs I get

> 01-18 16:51:39.368  27426-27426/com.example.se414011.musicapp1
>   W/MediaRecorder﹕ mediarecorder went away with unhandled events 01-18
>   16:51:42.598  27426-27426/com.example.se414011.musicapp1 A/libc﹕ Fatal
>   signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000010 (code=1), thread 27426
>   (14011.musicapp1)

Any help would be great thanks!

This is my code

```
public void start(View view) {
        try {
            myRecorder.prepare();
            myRecorder.start();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // start:it is called before prepare()
            // prepare: it is called after start() or before setOutputFormat()
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // prepare() fails
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        text.setText("Recording Status: Recording");
        stopBtn.setEnabled(true);
        startBtn.setEnabled(false);


        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start recording...",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    public void stop(View view) {
        try {
            myRecorder.stop();
            myRecorder.release();

            text.setText("Recording Status: Stop recording");
            stopBtn.setEnabled(false);
            startBtn.setEnabled(true);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop recording...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            //  it is called before start()
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            // no valid audio/video data has been received
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void play(View view) {
        try {
            myPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            myPlayer.setDataSource(outputFile);
            myPlayer.prepare();
            myPlayer.start();

            text.setText("Recording Status: Playing");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start play the recording...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    public void stopPlay(View view) {
        try {
            if (myPlayer != null) {
                myPlayer.stop();
                myPlayer.release();
                myPlayer = null;
                playBtn.setEnabled(true);
                startBtn.setEnabled(true);
                stopPlayBtn.setEnabled(false);
                text.setText("Recording Status: Stop playing");

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Stop playing the recording...",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can see in [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), you can reuse your MediaRecorder only if you don't release it, snippet:

```
 MediaRecorder recorder = new MediaRecorder();
 recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
 recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
 recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
 recorder.setOutputFile(PATH_NAME);
 recorder.prepare();
 recorder.start();   // Recording is now started
 ...
 recorder.stop();
 recorder.reset();   // You can reuse the object by going back to setAudioSource() step
 recorder.release(); // Now the object cannot be reused
```

You didn't post where you set your object `myRecorder`, and if you create a new one when you want to record again, but if you're reusing the same object after calling `release()` you'll be in problems, my suggestions are don't release it until you're finished or create a new MediaRecorder for each record.

```
boolean stopped = false;

public void start(View view) {
    //your code...
    stopped = false;
} 
 public void stop(View view) {
        try {
            myRecorder.stop();
            //myRecorder.release();
            stopped = true;

            //your code
        }
}

public void onDestroy(){
    if(stopped)
        myRecorder.release();
}
```

Comment: This lets me record again thanks but  now I cannot stop the second time I record. It gives me the error 

01-18 17:28:20.958  17470-17470/com.example.se414011.musicapp1 E/MediaRecorder﹕ stop called in an invalid state: 1

Comment: Then maybe the best way is to create a new MediaRecorder for each recording

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Sorry :S Thanks so much for the help so far!